# Why is async request with await not waiting for the response data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, async-await

im not sure why await is not working for me, can someone help me out?
I followed some guides and copied it exactly the same but still won't work.
I need CardsID array to be filled before calling console.log(CardsID.length)

code:

````
  "[LL_REPTAG_URLPREFIXFULL /]/api/v2/businessworkspaces?where_workspace_type_id=54";

async function postData() {
  let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.

    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      OTCSTicket: "[LL_REPTAG_OTCSTICKET /]",
    },

    //body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });

  return await response.json();
}

//(async function(){

postData().then(function (data) {
  // Log the data to the console
  // You would do something with both sets of data here
  //console.log(data);

  data.results.forEach((element) => {
    CardsID.push(element.data.properties.id);
    console.log("added");
  });
});
//})();

console.log(CardsID.length);
console.log(CardsID);```

result (console):

0
[]
[]
[]
24 added
````

Comment: Where do you expect to see the result?
`return await response.json();` should be `return response.json();` because you have already the await for response. In the `postData().then(function (data){}` callback you should fire the console log for `data` which you commented out.
The console.logs that placed outside of your functions won't wait for the async functions.

Comment: Your console.log calls should be inside the `.then(function(data) {` block

Comment: @Kaiido thank you so much, i was logging outside of 'then' block where it doesnt wait for async function to finish

Comment: @monkey-0001 did these modification and it worked! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the console.logs immediately after the postData() call, which is async (well, promise) and therefore won't wait for the execution to finish.
Either you need to place the console.logs inside the then handler, like this:

```
postData().then(function (data) {
  data.results.forEach((element) => {
    CardsID.push(element.data.properties.id);
    console.log("added");
  });

  console.log(CardsID.length);
  console.log(CardsID);
});
```

Or (for the sake of consistency), you could make it all async/await, eg.:

```
async function postData() {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      OTCSTicket: "[LL_REPTAG_OTCSTICKET /]",
    },
  });
  return await response.json();
}

async function run() {
  const data = await postData();

  const CardsID = [];
  for (const element of data.results) {
    CardID.push(element.data.properties.id);
    console.log("added");
  }

  console.log(CardsID.length);
  console.log(CardsID);
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that code in the `postData().then` block is executed asynchronously, after the promise get resolved. The `console.log(CardsID.length)` statement will run before the `then` block get executed.

To fix that, you can run the `console.log` statement in the promise callback.

```js
postData().then(function (data) {

  data.results.forEach((element) => {
    CardsID.push(element.data.properties.id);
    console.log("added");
  });

  // move the console.log statement here
  console.log(CardsID.length);
  console.log(CardsID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that your code below the .then block will run before it resolves because Javascript waits to resolve but continues through its synchronous run to execute the code below the any asynchronous code.